# Python Beautiful Soup Error : list index out of range

Tags: python

I am getting the following error with the script, i want to do is,

if i get a correct URL, i want it to check with BeautifulSoup if there is a form with value button "Send"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester.py", line 27, in 
    if viewstate[0]['value'] == "Send":
IndexError: list index out of range

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import urllib2
import sys
import os

url = sys.argv[1]
open_dir_list = open("dirlist.txt",'r')
dirs = open_dir_list.read().split("\n")
open_dir_list.close()

for dir in dirs:

        uri = url+"/"+dir

        try:
                from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
                response = urllib2.urlopen(uri)
                if response.getcode() == 200:
                        s = uri
                        soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(uri)
                        viewstate = soup.findAll("input", {"type": "submit"})
                        if viewstate[0]['value'] == "Send":
                                print("Yay!!!")
                        else:
                                print("There's nothing here")
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                if e.code == 401:
                        print "[!] Authorization Required %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 403:
                        print "[!] Forbidden %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 404:
                        print "[-] Not Found %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 503:
                        print "[!] Service Unavailable %s " % (uri)
                else:
                        print "[?] Unknwon"



print "\n:. FINISH :.\n"
```

It is working fine with this script, but it only checks only a given path

```
import urllib
f = urllib.urlopen("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/button.jsp")
s = f.read()
f.close()

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(s)

viewstate = soup.findAll("input", {"type": "submit"})
if viewstate[0]['value'] == "Send":
        print(" Yay!!!")
else:
        print("No Submit Button")
```

Comment: Surely `soup.findAll("input", {"type": "submit"})` is not going to work for every website? Also `'value'` is not going to always be there, you need to handle those cases with a try/except

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have given a website which has the value in it. and still i get the same error

Comment: Then your find_all is wrong, add a url

Comment: @PadraicCunningham See, i tested fine with that script below. but when i merge it with the script above, it's giving me an error, any idea ?

Comment: You are passing `uri = url+"/"+dir` not .read

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i am really noob at this, could you explain a bit more how i can fix it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32029148/2141635

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it's working now , but still getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from what I mentioned in a comment you are not passing the returned html you are passing `uri = url+"/"+dir` instead of `response.read()` to `BeautifulSoup` so you are searching for the tag in `uri` which I imagine  certainly does not contain any tags. You need to pass `read` as below:

```
     response = urllib2.urlopen(uri)
            if response.getcode() == 200:                       
                    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(response.read())
```

If you want the first match use `.find` using  `if viewstate` to make sure it matched something, you can also iterate over the file object getting a line at a time:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
import urllib2
import sys

url = sys.argv[1]
with  open("dirlist.txt",'r') as f:
    for dir in f:
        uri = url + "/" + dir.rstrip()
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(uri)
            if response.getcode() == 200:
                    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(response.read())
                    viewstate = soup.find("input", {"type": "submit"})
                    if viewstate and viewstate.get("value") == "Send":
                        print("Shell is found!! Yay!!!")
                    else:
                        print("There's nothing here")
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
                if e.code == 401:
                    print "[!] Authorization Required %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 403:
                    print "[!] Forbidden %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 404:
                    print "[-] Not Found %s " % (uri)
                elif e.code == 503:
                    print "[!] Service Unavailable %s " % (uri)
                else:
                    print "[?] Unknwon"



    print "\n:. FINISH :.\n"
```

Comment: kool :D it's working now, but still am getting IndexError. How to solve that ?

Comment: i put a try after `if response.getcode() == 200:` except after `print("There's nothing here')`still getting the same error

Comment: The error has nothing to do with a response, I will edit the answer, why are you not using beautifulSoup4?

Comment: err, am not python literate, i know very little of it, i am using ppl's code, and trying to get it right :/ i dunno how to use BeautifulSoup4

Comment: You should `pip install  Beautifulsoup4` and use `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` using from  `BeautifulSoup(response.read())`

Comment: Cool :D It's working perfectly, i changed it to Beautifulsoup4 too. thanks for the help @PadraicCunningham

Comment: i am trying to achieve multithreading here, could you help pls
http://stackoverflow.com/q/32047449/1656904